# How to make an EditText inactive, keeping the cursor always visible

Tags: java, android, xml

I develop a keyboard with text area and buttons. By clicking a button, the text area receives the button text as an input. I made the text area inactive to prevent other inputs, but it's needed to control the cursor's position to enable text entering and erasing from any position.

```
android:enabled="false"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

But the cursor disappears. How can I make it always visible?

Comment: In a Java code you can try `editText.setCursorVisible(true);` As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283354/how-to-have-fixed-cursor-position-for-edittext?rq=1#answer-35284134)

Comment: I tried it also in xml, but the cursor isn't visible.